# Bind to event handler from library class

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I would like override OnPreInit asp.net event and add code to it **from library class**. Is it possible?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. You normally don't override events, you subscribe to them - what do you want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understand your question, but you can override OnPreInit like this:

```
 protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
 {
     base.OnPreInit(e);

     //add your logic here
 }
```

Hope this answers your question.